# NSInvalidArgumentException when using a value extracted from JSON data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I am trying to retrieve value for `id`:

```
{"id":1,"name":"XYZ"}
```

When I use:

```
NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSArray * myPeople = [jsonData JSONValue]; 

NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] init]; 
NSDictionary *person = [myPeople objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
name = [NSString stringWithString:[person valueForKey:@"id"]]; 
name = [name stringByAppendingString:@". "]; 
name = [name stringByAppendingString:[person valueForKey:@"name"]]; 
name = [name stringByAppendingString:[person valueForKey:@"id"]]; 

cell.textLabel.text = name;
```

I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
reason: '-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e7f8b0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Suggestion: instead of writing "Please help", post the text of the compiler error.

Comment: I've not used the JSON library your using but the code you provided looks ok. The exception says that `length` is being called on `NSNumber` can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: That's not a compiler error.  At the very least you need to learn the difference between compile time and run time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling both `stringWithString:` and `stringByAppendingString:` but then passing in an `NSNumber`

You need to get the string value of the `NSNumber`

```
[[person valueForKey:@"id"] stringValue];
```

or use a format like:

```
name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", name, [person valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

I would also consider changing the structure slightly to make it easier to follow like this:

```
NSDictionary *person = [myPeople objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *personName = [person valueForKey:@"name"];
NSSNumber *personId  = [person valueForKey:@"id"];

NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@ %@", personId, personName, personId];
```

For sorting you want to make sure you are not pulling that data every time you set up a cell (looks like you are) or it will be a terrible experience.

I'm sure someone can point you to a better way of sorting but the quickest thing I can think of is

```
NSArray *myPeople = [[jsonData JSONValue] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
  return [[obj1 objectForKey:@"id"] compare:[obj2 objectForKey:@"id"]];
}]
```

Comment: I had another query, the JSON data that I obtain from a URL is :
[{"id":1,"name":"XYZ"},{"id":3,"name":"PQR"},{"id":2,"name":"ABC"}. I want to display them in a cell for a table in a sorted form on the asia of their id. Can u please guide me

Comment: This was of great help!! :) Really appreciate your help

Comment: Hey, just a quick question.. Could you suggest me an option how to design and implement a rating field. I saw on the internet that there are couple of options such as Textfield with Number formatter, radio group, comboBox which I could use. Please et me know, which is for suitable and how to implement it. Also, when I selected View->Utilities- > show objects Library in Xcode 4 it just shows the objects and not the objects library which I saw on the internet can u please guide me for that too

Comment: When you get a question it's best to try searching first. If you can't find an answer then ask a new question. If you ask in the comments then it's becomes difficult for someone else with the same problem to discover any answer given.

Comment: sorry, will take care next time! :)